# Sort and Group in one MongoDB query

Tags: php, mongodb

I have one collection "activity_logs" in MongoDB with following data,

```
{
   "_id": "lg1",
   "action": "create_event",       
   "business_id": "bs1",
   "event_id": "event1",
   "log_date": ISODate("2015-08-20T19:30:46.0Z") 
},
{
       "_id": "lg2",
       "action": "create_deal",       
       "business_id": "bs1",
       "deal_id": "deal1",
       "log_date": ISODate("2015-08-17T19:20:46.0Z") 
},
{
       "_id": "lg3",
       "action": "deal_used",
       "cust_id": "cust1",       
       "business_id": "bs1",
       "deal_id": "deal1",
       "log_date": ISODate("2015-08-17T19:25:46.0Z") 
},
{
       "_id": "lg3",
       "action": "deal_used",
       "cust_id": "cust2",       
       "business_id": "bs1",
       "deal_id": "deal1",
       "log_date": ISODate("2015-08-18T11:25:46.0Z") 
},
{
       "_id": "lg4",
       "action": "create_deal",       
       "business_id": "bs1",
       "deal_id": "deal2",
       "log_date": ISODate("2015-08-18T19:20:46.0Z") 
},
{
       "_id": "lg5",
       "action": "create_deal",       
       "business_id": "bs2",
       "deal_id": "deal3",
       "log_date": ISODate("2015-08-19T19:20:46.0Z") 
},
{
       "_id": "lg6",
       "action": "create_events",       
       "business_id": "bs3",
       "event_id": "event5",
       "log_date": ISODate("2015-07-18T19:22:46.0Z") 
},
{
       "_id": "lg7",
       "action": "deal_used",       
       "business_id": "bs2",
       "cust_id": "cust5"
       "deal_id": "deal3",
       "log_date": ISODate("2015-08-17T19:20:46.0Z") 
}
```

I want to fetch all record with group of action taken with that business & latest first.
If business create any latest deal then I need to show **xyx create new deal1**,
If 2 customers used that deal then I want to show **2 users used deal1 of xyz business**.

So output will look like,

```
business_id       action       deal_id     event_id    users_count    log_date
       bs1         create_event       -         event1     -             ISODate("2015-08-20T19:30:46.0Z") 
       bs2         create_deal      deal3         -    -             ISODate("2015-08-19T19:20:46.0Z")
       bs3         create_event       -         event5    -            ISODate("2015-07-18T19:22:46.0Z")
       bs1         create_deal      deal2         -      -            ISODate("2015-07-18T19:20:46.0Z")
       bs1          deal_used       deal2         -       2            ISODate("2015-07-18T11:25:46.0Z")
       bs1         create_deal      deal1         -        -             ISODate("2015-08-17T19:20:46.0Z")
       bs2          deal_used       deal3         -         -             ISODate("2015-08-17T19:20:46.0Z")
```

Output will be group of action,deal,event,pro.

I have tried below query but this is not satisfy all,

```
db.activity_logs.group({
    "key": {
        "action": true,
        "shared_action": true,
        "business_id": true,
        "event_id": true,
        "deals_id": true,
        "deal_id": true
    },
    "initial": {
        "count_id": 0
    },
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
        if (obj._id != null) if (obj._id instanceof Array) prev.count_id += obj._id.length;
        else prev.count_id++;
    }
});
```

Please help me for same.
And suggest me If I can do it by using aggregate.

Comment: I ask only an operational question. Which field in your document is the "user"? "cus_id" maybe? But is is not present in all th objects

Comment: "cust_id" is for user.

Comment: Well I thought so. So again, not present in all objects. Is it meant to be there?

Comment: If any user used deal then only I insert that cust_id and "action": "deal_used".

Comment: Therefore meaning if "no user" then "no count", correct?

Comment: Yes, as I shown in expected output if user used deal then only count of user else only remaining data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After huge research I found answer for my question with aggregation. I am posting it for just help to others, who are facing such difficulties,

```
$array = array(
            array('$project' => array( '_id' => 1,'action'=>1, 'business_id'=>1,'event_id' => 1, 'deal_id' => 1, 'cust_id' => 1,'log_date' => 1)),
            array('$group' => array("_id" => array('action' => '$action',"pro_id" => '$pro_id',"event_id" => '$event_id', "deal_id" => '$deal_id'),'count' => array('$sum' => 1),'lastDate' => array( '$last' => '$log_date'))),
            array('$skip'=>$list),
            array('$limit'=>1000),
            array('$sort'=>array('log_date'=> -1)),
        );

        $results = $collection_activity_logs->aggregate($array);
```